# how to wrap XADataSource using aries transaction jdbc

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, xa

I am using pax jdbc 1.1.0 within karaf 4.1.2.

here is my file for data source (org.ops4j.datasource-application1.cfg)

```
osgi.jdbc.driver.name=mysql
pool=dbcp2
xa=true
jdbc.pool.testOnBorrow=true
jdbc.pool.blockWhenExhausted=true
jdbc.pool.maxWaitMillis=400
url=jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/application1?characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&autoReconnectForPools=true
user=xxx
password=yyy
dataSourceName=application1
```

While using it with jms-activemq I got following error

```
| ERROR | DefaultQuartzScheduler-com.application1.olm.Order-service-quartzCamelPublisher_Worker-5 | Transaction                      | 177 - org.apache.aries.transaction.manager - 1.3.3 | Please correct the integration and supply a NamedXAResource
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot log transactions as com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4MysqlXAConnection@3df4d31d is not a NamedXAResource.
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl$TransactionBranch.getResourceName(TransactionImpl.java:781) [177:org.apache.aries.transaction.manager:1.3.3]
```

here it is suggested to "For jdbc you can wrap your XADataSource using aries transaction jdbc.", how can I do that ?

[Why am I getting "is not a NamedXAResource" in Apache Karaf 4.0.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038491/why-am-i-getting-is-not-a-namedxaresource-in-apache-karaf-4-0-4/35039542)